# Compiling error while trying to print volume of the largest box and the length the width and the height

Tags: java

I am getting the error "double can not be dereferenced". on the code below the problem is coming from the second for loop starting with j. I can only use one dimensional arrays so my approach to this problem in my head was to kind of do it as if i had two dimensional arrays with two for loops. I don't know if this is possible since i keep getting the same error. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated and if you dont understand something please ask.

```
       public class FedEx12{
            public static void largestBoxMeasurementsAndVolume(double [] lengthArray , double [] widthArray,double [] heightArray){
            double boxVolume1 = lengthArray[0]*widthArray[0]*heightArray[0];
            double boxVolume2 = lengthArray[1]*widthArray[1]*heightArray[1];
            double boxVolume3 = lengthArray[2]*widthArray[2]*heightArray[2];
            double boxVolume4 = lengthArray[3]*widthArray[3]*heightArray[3];
            double boxVolume5 = lengthArray[4]*widthArray[4]*heightArray[4];
            double [] totalBoxVolumes = {boxVolume1, boxVolume2, boxVolume3, boxVolume4, boxVolume5};
            double max = totalBoxVolumes[0];
                for (int i = 0; i < totalBoxVolumes.length;i++){
                    if(max < totalBoxVolumes[i])
                          max = (totalBoxVolumes[i]);       
                          for (int j = 0; j < totalBoxVolumes[0].length;j++){
                                System.out.println(max + "\n" + lengthArray[j] + "\n" + widthArray[j] + "\n" + heightArray[j]);
        }
        }
 }
```

}

This is the error im getting

```
FedEx12.java:16: error: double cannot be dereferenced
                    for (int j = 0; j < totalBoxVolumes[0].length;j++){
                                                          ^
```

1 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've defined `totalBoxVolumes` array in this form :

```
double [] totalBoxVolumes = {boxVolume1, boxVolume2, boxVolume3, boxVolume4, boxVolume5};
```

so it is a 1D array , this code is valid :

```
totalBoxVolumes.length;
```

but you can't use the bellow code :

```
totalBoxVolumes[0].length;
```

**`totalBoxVolumes[0].length;`** is valid for 2D array or more dimensions

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to use `totalBoxVolumes.length`, which will return the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call a method on the content of `totalBoxVolumes[0].length`, which contains a primitive type (double).

You want to call the method on the array itself, so `totalBoxVolumes.lenght`.